# BOOL is returning YES for value 0 in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have `Invisible = 0` in my model and I am trying get this in `BOOL` using this line.

```
BOOL invisible = [self.model objectForKey:@"Invisible"];
```

but invisible is YES instead of NO. I've also tried with bool but it is also true. I checked class of the object using `[[self.model objectForKey:@"Invisible"] class]` and it is showing _NSCFBoolean. What's wrong here? model is NSDictionary.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Okay so I found the real issue. I have Filter class where I have getter isInvisible and code is

```
- (BOOL)isInvisible {
     return [[self.model objectForKey:@"Invisible"] boolValue]; 
   }
```

When I call this first time it returns me NO. Which is good. Now immediately after that I call it again and it returns <nil>. Strange.

```
(lldb) po filter.isInvisible 
NO 
(lldb) po filter.isInvisible 
<nil>
```

There is only 1 second difference between two po commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`= [self.model objectForKey:@"Invisible"];`

This will return an `NSNumber` object. If you want a `BOOL` primitive you can get it via the `boolValue` method so

`= [[self.model objectForKey:@"Invisible"] boolValue];`

Comment: Okay so here is my code. I have Filter class where I have getter isInvisible and code is 

- (BOOL)isInvisible
{
    return [[self.model objectForKey:@"Invisible"] boolValue];
}

When I call this first time it returns me NO. Which is good. Now immediately after that I call it again and it returns <nil>. Strange.

(lldb) po filter.isInvisible
NO

(lldb) po filter.isInvisible
<nil>

There is only 1 second difference between two po commands.

Comment: your code seems fine. However share the code where dictionary code is written. Also why are you using lldb,po for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Since you return `BOOL` value from `isInvisible` method,  I believe `nil` is equivalent to 0. So 0 is equivalent to `NO` or `false`. hence `filter.isInvisible` should be `NO` or `false`.

Please just verify that in `if` statement in your code.

Example:

```
if (filter.isInvisible == NO){//Should be reached here}
```